# just todays agenda for just the current buffer

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I would like to make a quick access agenda for today and just for the current buffer.

So my approach looks like this, but it does not work.

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
   '(
     ("o"                                ;; Key
      "todays agenda for current buffer" ;; Description
      agenda                             ;; Type agenda
      ((org-agenda-files `(,(buffer-file-name))) 
       (org-agenda-span 1))              ;; Options
     )))
```

I found some inspiration [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html) but it does not really work here atm.

I know you can narrow the agenda to current buffer with < but if it is possible I would prefer to use a custom agenda.

An explanation why this approach does not work would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem is that you have forgotten a mandatory piece in the command. `C-h v org-agenda-custom-commands` says in part:

```
Each entry is a list like this:

   (key desc type match settings files)

...

type     The command type, any of the following symbols:
          agenda      The daily/weekly agenda.
...
match    What to search for:
          ...
          For all other commands, this should be the empty string.
settings  A list of option settings, similar to that in a let form, so like
          this: ((opt1 val1) (opt2 val2) ...).   The values will be
          evaluated at the moment of execution, so quote them when needed.
...
```

Since you are not using a match you just omitted it, but that's not correct: **For all other commands, this** (i.e. the match expression) **should be the empty string.**
So it is looking for a match expression and since there is no empty string there, it goes after the settings instead and tries to interpret them as a match expression, with predictably chaotic results.

Try this:

```el
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
   '(
     ("o"                                ;; Key
      "todays agenda for current buffer" ;; Description
      agenda                             ;; Type agenda
      ""                                 ;; Match expression
      ((org-agenda-files `(,(buffer-file-name))) 
       (org-agenda-span 1))              ;; Options
     )))
```

That seems to have worked in my (rather superficial) experiment.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain! For me it works under two conditions: if the current buffer is also an agenda-file and if sticky agenda is disabled. If it's not in the usual agenda-list I see the error `if: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil` and if I refresh the agenda the error is `let*: Args out of range: 0, 0` Does refreshing the agenda work for you?

Comment: I tested it starting from `emacs -q` where I don't have *any* files in the agenda (and certainly no sticky agenda): it seems to work in that case. I am not sure what happens when you refresh the agenda, but I can try it later on today and let you know.

Comment: I tried out `emacs -q` and it worked even if the file is not in the agenda. But refreshing did not work for me, neither did changing to the next day. If you confirm, then I might start another question about why this occurs. Would you support this suggestion?

Comment: Yes, refreshing does not work fro me either. I believe that has to do with the local binding of org-agenda-files in the settings above: `buffer-file-name` returns nil since there is no file associated with the agenda buffer. By all means, ask another question: you do not need my support for that (or for anything else for that matter).