# Refresh agenda for (dynamic) current buffer

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

When I use this custom agenda (below) for a current buffer, the agenda builds correctly. But if I try to refresh it or move the date with `f` or `b` I get errors like: `if: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil` and `let*: Args out of range: 0, 0`

```el
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
   '(
     ("o"                                ;; Key
      "todays agenda for current buffer" ;; Description
      agenda                             ;; Type agenda
      ""                                 ;; Match expression
      ((org-agenda-files `(,(buffer-file-name))) 
       (org-agenda-span 1))              ;; Options
     )))
```

How can I make the agenda refreshable?

Comment: As I explained in a comment in your [other question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/59918/just-todays-agenda-for-just-the-current-buffer), `buffer-file-name` returns nil in the agenda buffer (i.e. there is no file associated with the agenda buffer).  So your `org-agenda-files` is empty and that causes the error you are getting.

Comment: I did not get it that first time, but I think now I do. So I will change the question to how can I make the agenda refrashable.

Comment: I think that's best: I'm not sure that you can do what you want in the way you go about it, so it's probably better to ask a less-specific question, but make sure to explain exactly *what* you want to accomplish (and leave the *how* to whoever answers).